# How to extract elements of a Pandas series using a list index

Tags: python, pandas

I know to select items from a Pandas series using a list of indexes like so:

```
yields = pd.Series([26.6,23.7,28.5,14.2,17.9,24.3,29.9,11.4,25.3,16.5,21.1])
print(yields.iloc[[1,3,5]])
```

My question is: how do I select items that are not in a list of indexes? That is, how can I use this list of 3 indexes to select the other 8 items in the series? In other contexts, I have seen the word 'masking' used to describe what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use boolean indexing based on the absence of an index in your list:

```
yields[~yields.index.isin([1, 3, 5])]
```

By the way, in your original case `yields[[1,3,5]]` is as good as `yields.iloc[[1,3,5]]`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Use [`sets`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)

- [`difference`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference)

  - `s.difference(t)` → `s - t`
  - new set with elements in s but not in t

```py
print(yields.iloc[yields.index.difference([1,3,5])])


0     26.6
2     28.5
4     17.9
6     29.9
7     11.4
8     25.3
9     16.5
10    21.1
```